# Bash script: Checking today's date against a date without year

Tags: bash

I'd like to send a renewal reminder email out four weeks before an expiry date. I'm storing all the details in an array, but I can't figure out how I check if today's date is 28 days before the date in the array.

Here's what I've got so far, any help with how to do the date checking would be much appreciated:

```
#!/bin/sh

adminemail="me@gmail.com"

account[1]="June 03|john@gmail.com|John"
account[2]="April 17|jane@gmail.com|Jane"
account[3]="November 29|sarah@gmail.com|Sarah"

for check in "${account[@]}"
do
    renew=$(echo $check | cut -f1 -d\|)
    email=$(echo $check | cut -f2 -d\|)
    name=$(echo $check | cut -f3 -d\|)

    # check date is 28 days away
    if [ ?????? ]
    then
        subject="Your account is due for renewal"
        text="
Dear $name,

Your account is due for renewal by $renew. blah blah blah"

        echo "$text" | mail -s "$subject" $email -- -r $adminemail
    fi
done
```

Comment: you can use `date --date='-28 days'` to get the date 28 days ago or `date --date='28 days'` to get 28 days in future. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful start. But how do I then compare that to my date, as presumably it will have a year in it while mine doesn't (because it's recurring)?

Comment: What if the expiry date is February 29?

Comment: `date +%m-%d --date='28 days'` -- to get `month:day` But you will have to handle `dec` or `jan` dates..so year may be useful to have. use `%B` instead of `%m` if you want `month` as `locale's full month name`

Comment: @SimonBlackbourn: `date +'%B %d' --date='28 days'` will give you the date 10 days from now in the form `January 01`. (Note: you'll want to check that the month-names in your account-listings match the month-names on your system, since these are locale-sensitive.)

Comment: You'll want to change the hashbang to `#!/bin/bash` if you are using `bash`-specific features such as arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the month and date of 28 days before the `check` date like this:

```
warning_date=$(date --date='June 03 -28 days' +%s)
```

The current date in the same format:

```
current_date=$(date +%s)
```

Since they are both numeric and in the same scale (seconds since epoch), now you can check if `$current_date` is greater than `$warning_date`:

```
if [ $warning_date -lt $current_date ]; then
  # ...
fi
```

Put it all together now:

```
# ...
current_date=$(date +%s)

for check in ${account[@]}; do
  # ...
  renew=$(echo $check | cut -f1 -d\|)

  # 28 days before the account renewal date
  warning_date=$(date --date="$renew -28 days" +%m%d)

  if [ $warning_date -lt $current_date ]; then
    # Set up your email and send it.
  fi
done
```

#### Update

To be reminded only if current date is the 28th day prior to the `check` date you can get each date in the same month date format and compare for string equality:

```
# ...
current_date=$(date "+%B %d")

for check in ${account[@]}; do
  # ...
  renew=$(echo $check | cut -f1 -d\|)

  # The 28th day before the account renewal day
  warning_date=$(date --date="$renew -28 days" "%B %d")

  if [ $warning_date == $current_date ]; then
    # Set up your email and send it.
  fi
done
```

Comment: this is almost there & helped me get to the solution: it sends a reminder every day for 28 days, not just on the 28th day before, so changing the date format from `%s` to `"%B %d"` and the conditional to `if [ "$warning_date" == "$current_date" ]` sorts it out though. if you update the answer i'll mark it as accepted. thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful! I've added the update to the answer according to your solution.

Comment: +1 This was more or less going to be my answer. Simon, _accept_ this answer if this answered your question by clicking on the checkmark to the left side of the question.

Answer (score 3):

It's best to use Unix timestamps for date comparisons, as they are simple integers.

```
#!/bin/bash

adminemail="me@gmail.com"

account[1]="June 03|john@gmail.com|John"
account[2]="April 17|jane@gmail.com|Jane"
account[3]="November 29|sarah@gmail.com|Sarah"

for check in "${account[@]}"
do
    IFS="|" read renew email name <<< "$check"

    # GNU date assumed. Similar commands are available for BSD date
    ts=$( date +%s --date "$renew" )
    now=$( date +%s )
    (( ts < now )) && (( ts+=365*24*3600 )) # Check the upcoming date, not the previous

    TMINUS_28_days=$(( ts - 28*24*3600 ))
    TMINUS_29_days=$(( ts - 29*24*3600 ))
    if (( TMINUS_29_days < now && now <  TMINUS_28_days)); then        
        subject="Your account is due for renewal"
        mail -s "$subject" "$email" -- -r "$adminemail" <<EOF
Dear $name,

Your account is due for renewal by $renew. blah blah blah
EOF    
    fi
done
```

Comment: thanks very much, as with @amesee's answer the problem with this is it will send a reminder every day for 28 days, rather than just on the 28th day before. however you've taught me a bunch of very helpful stuff about bash scripts - cheers!

Comment: Ah, you're right. (Somewhat) easily fixed, as it depends on how often you run the script. For this answer, I'll assume once a day, but you can adjust the window to suit your schedule. It's also warning at some point in the 24 hours before the 28th day, but again, you can adjust as desired. (28 and 27 days might be the appropriate range).

Comment: Integers may be faster than strings in a compiled language but this is shell script. And you had to use twice as much code to accomplish that same task. IMHO, readability should be the priority in bash, not speed. Also, once you dive into timestamps you have to worry about handing DST and Timezones properly.

Comment: @swdev It's not an issue of integers vs strings, it's a matter of working with a format with which you can do arithmetic. Not all versions of `date` can do arithmetic like shown in the accepted answer (it's a GNU extension, I think). Since we're only concerned with the interval between two dates, it doesn't actually matter which timezone is used, as long as the same timezone is used for both calls to `date`.